# What does sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 mean?

Tags: pcl, sensor-msgs, ros-hydro, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to ask a next question to somebody who is familiar with PCL in ROS.
**What does sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 mean?**
On this page (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials), Wiki instructs Hydro users to use `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` instead of `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` in a callback function. 
Actually, I can't build execute file of example.cpp on /pcl/Tutorials if I use `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.
Is `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` never used on Hydro?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157246/what-does-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2-mean?/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When it was first being developed, PCL had a very close relationship with ROS. It was only recently that PCL has become completely independent of ROS, after some code refactoring.

ROS has always had its own point cloud data structure (`sensor_msgs::PointCloud` and then `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`), which was initially used at least partially by PCL. So `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` exists today mostly for compatibility with ROS.

I am working with PCL in Hydro, so if you let me know where exactly you're having issues (either by asking a new question, which is better, or editing this one) I might be able to give you some pointers.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-24**:
@georgebrindeiro, Thank you for replying early! The one of thing I want to know is how to pass ROS topic (that means sensor infomation) to callback function. I have thought that the role is sensor_msg::PointCloud.
My idea is wrong, isn't it? I will rely on you when I have new issues. Thanks!

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2014-04-27**:
When using ROS, you use sensor_msgs::PointCloud2. When using PCL, you use PCL types. To convert from ROS to PCL cloud type, use the pcl_conversions::toPCL function. To convert back, use pcl_conversions::fromPCL. See http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-05-20**:
Have you had any luck saving PCD files with ROS and PCL?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2014-05-22**:
@Athoesen yeah, no problem. if you're having problems with that, though, you should probably start a new thread.